# IN clause limitation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the limit for the size of a value set for the IN operator in BigQuery? For example is it ok to put 100k values in IN clause? Like `... where id in ([100k ids is here]) ...`

I haven't find any mentions about it at manuals, however there should be a boundary when it's better to use temp table with a join from a performance point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be limited by the *length of query* you're going to submit to BigQuery.

[image]

- See also - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs